# Error with sending PushNotifications with OneSignal android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I am working on a Messaging Android App. Users should be notified with a push notification.

At the time I have this code:

```
public void notifyUser(String user_id, String message) {
        try {
            OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en':['" + message + "']}, " +
                            "'include_player_ids': ['" + user_id + "'], " +
                            "'headings': {'en': 'Tag sub Title HI {{user_name}}'}, " +
                            "'data': {'openURL': 'https://imgur.com'}," +
                            "'buttons':[{'id': 'id1', 'text': 'Go to GreenActivity'}, {'id':'id2', 'text': 'Go to MainActivity'}]}"),
                    new OneSignal.PostNotificationResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("LOL", "postNotification Success: " + response.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("LOL", "postNotification Failure: " + response.toString());
                        }
                    });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But I get an Error in Log:

```
D/LOL: postNotification Failure: {"errors":["Notification contents for each language must be a string"]}
```

I searched threw the Internet but didn't find a solution for my Problem.
I hope you can help me...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error you're seeing is because you're sending up the message inside an array when it should just be a string.

`"{'contents': {'en':['" + message + "']}` should be `"{'contents': {'en':'" + message + "'}` (removed the brackets).